# How to get Indian Rupee Symbol in Jasper Report with Amount having two zeros after the decimal place. Amount is having Datatype of Double

Tags: jasper-reports

I  am making project  with backend as SpringBoot  and frontend as thymleaf and Javscript.
I am  trying to generate to jasper report in which amount will come from the database which is postgres in this project .
Please help me and let  me know  how I will be able to get  Amount   with Indian Rupee symbol with two zeros after the  decimal place  in the jasper report eg:  ₹ 2000.00
Thanks to all for providing the valuable suggestion

I tried by changing the datatype of Amount column  from double to numeric in database  to get  two zeros after the decimal but it did not solved the problem , value was coming with  one zero after decimal place only eg :  2000.0
then to get  Rupee symbol  with two zeros after decimal place  I wrote below code
and then set it into the parameter :

parameters.put("TotalAmount",NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new
Locale("en","IN")).format(requestfortieuphotels.getTotalAmount()));

but Output came on jasper report as  Rs 2000.00
though, two zeros after decimal came but Rupee symbol (₹) did not come .

Please help me to know  how to get ₹ 2000.00  as amount in  jasperreport.

Answer (score 0):

According to the JDK release notes, you have locale codes hi_IN (Hindi) and en_IN (English).

Try this:

```html
parameters.put("TotalAmount",Currency.getInstance(new Locale("hi", "IN")).getSymbol()+requestfortieuphotels.getTotalAmount()));
```

[image: Running Code. Please check output]

Comment: Tried but  Rupee symbol  ₹ is not coming

Comment: @Prabhanshu Check the attached image for your reference.

Comment: Thanks , able to get indian rupee symbol now